MacOS15.2 cannot debug via vscode
As you can see, while debuging the pause button is grey and cannot stop at any breakpoint.
I used to use macos 12-13.x, sry I can't remember the detail version, and someday it just not work anymore, so I updated os version to 15.2 and it didn't work either.
I also updated and redownload vscode several times, and I can't find any similar questions like this on google/github.
Besides, I also tested cpp using codelldb, it didn't work either, and I can debug executable via lldb in terminal normally, when I connect a machine via remote-ssh, debugging behaviour performs same.
Any suggestions are welcomed, thanks.


{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/echo_server",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}


Is there any reason why you tagged "C++" there is nothing "C++" about your question

how you run python file

@mehdiahmadi sry I uploaded wrong picture, updated already, without launch.json, vscode just attach on the process.

what is the version of vs code

@PepijnKramer bcz I mainly can't debug cpp so I think maybe some cpp devloper might already faced and fixed this....

@mehdiahmadi Version: 1.96.0 (Universal)
Commit: 138f619c86f1199955d53b4166bef66ef252935c
Date: 2024-12-11T02:29:09.626Z
Electron: 32.2.6
ElectronBuildId: 10629634
Chromium: 128.0.6613.186
Node.js: 20.18.1
V8: 12.8.374.38-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 24.2.0

This question is similar to: VSCode: Why isn't debugger stopping at breakpoints?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@shengguolu No debugging C++ is something completely different. So do not tag C++. Have you read this C++ tag useage?

@PepijnKramer thx for the hint, I already removed that tag.


I found that I click the first button on touch bar all the time to start debugging, but this button means run without debug. I should click the second button, that's a stupid mistake :(

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
